# Ad failed to load : 0 WHEN USING TEST AD

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I'm struggling to implement adMob in my app i'm using test ad native id  in order to even see things work I keep having this error :

> Ad failed to load : 0

. I have seen some posts in here that it might be because account is not yet accepted on GoogleAdMob, but I'm using TEST ID, plus i made that account over 12 hours ago, I don't get it.

```
inner class AdItemViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    fun bind() {
        val adLoader:AdLoader = AdLoader.Builder(context, Constants.ADMOB_TEST_AD_UNIT_ID)
            .forNativeAd { nativeAd ->
                Log.i("TESt", "Ad downloaded succesfully ${nativeAd.body} , ${nativeAd.headline}")
                val styles: NativeTemplateStyle =
                    NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor(
                        ColorDrawable(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(
                                context,
                                R.color.gray_500
                            )
                        )
                    ).build();

                val template: TemplateView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_template);
                template.setStyles(styles);
                template.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
            }
            .build();

        adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
```

}

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" >

<!--  This is your template view -->
<com.erdees.foodcostcalc.ads.TemplateView
    android:id="@+id/my_template"
    app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_small_template_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I see in app empty ad layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have you added the device as testing device?**

**Ad failed to load 0 means ->** It could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and requesting for live ads. It could take a few hours for ads to start getting served if that is that case. If you are receiving test ads then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you are able to receive live ads then.

[Reference](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/fBe3YL3ffpo?pli=1)

Comment: Just leaving this comment here if somebody will have similar issue. When I added my device as a testing device and then started testing on my physical device I could see ads and everything worked, I have no idea why but for few hours before it started to work on emulator it was already working on device.